# Getting the phoneNumber using $cordovaContacts

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to get all the contacts in the phone using `ng-cordova`, I success to do that like the following, I create a service in AngularJS:

```
    .factory("ContactManager", function($cordovaContacts) {
    return {
        getContacts: function() {
            var options = {};
            options.filter = "";
            options.multiple = true;

            //get the phone contacts
            return $cordovaContacts.find(options);
        }
    }
})
```

Also the method `find` in the `ng-cordova` is't like the following:

```
 find: function (options) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    var fields = options.fields || ['id', 'displayName'];
    delete options.fields;

    navigator.contacts.find(fields, function (results) {
        q.resolve(results);
      },
      function (err) {
        q.reject(err);
      },
      options);

    return q.promise;
  }
```

And did the following inside the controller:

```
        ContactManager.getContacts().then(function(result){
            $scope.users= result;

        }, function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I noticed that in the `$scope.users` I find the `formatted, middleName ...`, but I can't find the phoneNumber, how can I get also the phoneNumbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `log` the contacts you should see an object with a `phoneNumbers` **array** in it.

```
   ContactManager.getContacts().then(function(result){
        $scope.users= result;
        console.log(result);
    ...
```

If you don't it's something else.

I also made a somewhat close mock **[json](http://beta.json-generator.com/KxG_c3Y)** of what the return looks like.